# How to check for two possible regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I would like to parse someone's home address to street, house number, city..

In my case there are two (very different) possible ways how can the data be formatted. So I have two very long regex expressions I would like to check for. If the regex match, I would like to export data from those regexes.

1:

```
Long Square
25
London
...
```

2:

```
London
Living: Long Square, 25
....
```

How should I check for both of these? Should I use **just two if clauses** and check them one by one like:

```
if (preg_match(@$match_regex, file_get_contents($tag->getAttribute("src")), $matches) == true)
{
  //regex 1 matched
}
else if ((preg_match(@$match_regex_2, file_get_contents($tag->getAttribute("src")), $matches) 
{
  //regex 2 matched
}
else
{
  //no match
}
```

Or should I check that somehow **in one regex**?

Like:

```
[regex_1|regex_2]
```

Which method is preffered and will be cpu "faster"?

Comment: I think you can get the info with much easier methods. ie: are those 2 formats always in the same pattern? `(place + linebreak + number + linebreak + City)` && `(City + linebreak + "Living" + colon + Place + number)` etc... If so, I would check for the colon and use `explode()` instead of using regex. You would be surprised how many times we can actually avoid using regex

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But the actual data are not about addresses, but comparing some JS code lines which are much more complex and can't be exploded. This was just an example to simplify things..

Comment: `@$match_regex` what are you trying here? Why would the variable ever **not** be set?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: ? I set `$match_regex = "/regex/i";` at the top of the code to make it easy to change later.

Comment: @JoudicekJouda Why the `@` sign? Usually it'd be there to hide notices, but it doesn't make any sense here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would be searching for `Living:` text, then do the regex:

```
$string = file_get_contents($tag->getAttribute("src"));
$matched = false;
$matches = array();

if (false === strpos($string, 'Living:')) {
    $matched = preg_match(@$match_regex, $string, $matches);
} else {
    $matched = preg_match(@$match_regex_2, $string, $matches);
}

if (!$matched) {
    // no match
} else {
    // print matches
}
```

Notice that I separated the two logics. First `if` block determines the type of the address string and performs proper regex. Second `if` block checks if the match occured (no matter which regex was performed).

Comment: This is perfect! I would never think about such a simple and clever solution. Going to try it now and will post results!

Answer (score 1):

Don't make assumptions about performance - measure it.

The one regex would be

```
(regex1)|(regex2)
```

When you have both version run them against your data and measure the time.